# Is there a visualization technique/statistical test to compare the growth rates of 2 treatment groups?

Tags: r, data-visualization

**Is there a visualization technique/statistical test to compare the growth rates of 2 treatment groups in which patients in each group do not all have the same number of weigh-in dates**

The data in the actual dataset are linear and have anywhere from 6 to 12 weigh-in dates per patient. Below is some dummy data:

```
library(plyr)

#Make some fake data
d1 <- data.frame(id = rep(c(1,4,2,6), each = 3), weight_kg = sample(0.5:2, 12, TRUE))
d2 <- data.frame(id = rep(c(1,4), each = 1), weight_kg = sample(0.5:2, 4, TRUE))
treatment <- c('ABX','control','ABX','control','ABX','control',
         'ABX','control','ABX','control','ABX',
         'control','ABX','control','ABX','control')
treatment <- as.factor(treatment)
data=rbind(d1,d2)
data$id <- as.factor(data$id)
date = seq(as.Date("2014-01-13"), as.Date("2015-4-13"), by="months")
metadata=cbind(data,treatment,date)
metadata =as.tibble(metadata)
```

I do not want to throw away data so I am looking for a way to posibly compare the average slope of patient's weight gain independent of when patients were weighed. Patients were not all enrolled and weighed at the same times as is common is most clinical studies.

Comment: You could do time since start of the study. i.e. Patient 1 starts on 4/1/2019 and gets weight on 4/9/2019, that would be day 8.  Then compare the slopes of the growth as a function of days since start of study instead of literal dates

Comment: G5W I guess you are right, it more of an algorithm question. NotThatKindODr you are suggesting to make a for-loop to iterate over each day of the study starting from the first day the first patient was weight up to the last day the last patient was weight? And grouping by treatment groups?

Comment: am i missing something? You calculate the time to the first weighing.. and plot the weight gain wrt to that for each patient..

Comment: Thank you. I fixed the problem by plotting weight gain due to treatment as a function of time in days instead of months. After, I ran a multivariable linear regression in r with weight and treatment as my covariants. Apologies for the simple question, the answer seems quite obvious now.